# Adding Single Line Tweet to Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, tweets

I am working on a website for a client, he wants his tweets at the top of the page. I am confused as to how this is going to work. I have been working with some 3rd party stuff, but no success.

This is the page I am working on:
http://whiterhino.us/jason_tanzer/template.html

This is how I want it to look/work:
http://whiterhino.us/jason_tanzer/sample.html

Any Help would be Great!

Comment: It would help if you made your question a bit more specific and technical. People aren't going to do your work for you (especially not without a bounty). For example: "How do I create a popup bubble in Javascript without effecting the existing rendering flow of the page?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging an external website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplest way to do it is using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=2"></script>
```

Just replace "username" with the client's username and the count to however many tweets you want to display. The style with CSS and you are done!

Answer (score -1):

Did this the other day. You probably want to use a library for this to make things easier. First get his twitter JSON feed (http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/.json?count=10&callback=?) using Jquery's getJSON(). Process the returned data accordingly.